# My property is an pointer to array, does it only have one setter - the pointer itself?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, properties, setter

I wish if there was some sort of setter mechanism whenever I set indexed values of a pointer to array property. Say if I had such a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat *components;
```

I'd want a setter whenever `self.components[0] = 1.0f` would be set, like so:

```
- (void)setComponent:(CGFloat)component index:(int)index
{
    self.components[index] = component;
    // Some other code I want executed with every set
}
```

Is this possible or should I just write my own methods for each component, and then just call them, instead of explicitly using C array indexed pointer = value?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of components?

Comment: Yes, it will always be a static number, why?

Comment: I thought I had an idea, but then I noticed that I had not read your question correctly :-). - I assume that it is not possible, unless you replace `CGFloat *` by a custom class that implements the "Array-Style Subscripting" methods (see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: That is a very useful link, Martin R! Thanks